# Can I connect to internet while other devices access via WIFI Router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

I have a normal WIFI router which we use for accessing internet. Now there is a requirement where we need to connect couple of data ports(Which reads some sensors and it has WIFI installed) to the WIFI Router. Then we have to access the router, read the data taken from each data port using a PC connected to the router. Also, we need to use the same WIFI router for accessing the internet, which is of course being used by the same PC which reads the data ports. Via internet we upload data to servers.

My question is, is it possible to have a local device access and internet access with the same router as above? If not, what is the correct procedure?

Comment: Can you please clarify... ? I mean a wifi router can allow access by both wired and wireless devices regardless of what they do (assuming they are simply trying to use network access as per normal, and not trying to do something nefarious like hijacking the network traffic). Anything connected to the same LAN (Local Area Network) can access each other (assuming access has been granted, or you know how to access them, and their local IP address), and access the internet at the same time (assuming internet access IS available).

Comment: @Darius: I think you provided the answer :)

Comment: @Darius you should convert your comment to an answer to be honest.

Comment: Simplified question: "Can computers, that are accessing the same hotspot, communicate with each other?"

Answer (score 0):

As suggested on the above comments to turn my original comments into answer (and added a bit extra details which hopefully is useful):

A WiFi router can allow access by both wired and wireless devices connected to it regardless of what those device do (assuming they are simply trying to use the network access as per normal, and not trying to do something nefarious like redirecting the network traffic).

Any devices connected to the same LAN (Local Area Network - on wired, and/or wireless) can access each other (#1), and access the internet at the same time (#2)

Caveat #1 - Assuming there are no setting to do any network isolation, and also you know their IP address, how to access those devices (specific port / protocol / method of access), and access to those devices has been granted (you have/guess/obtain the login credentials).

Caveat #2 - Assuming internet access is available generally to any devices on the same LAN and no restriction / isolation applied.